# Binding imageSource property change in List which is in-turn inside an object which is hosted in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

Consider a listbox containing custom objects (let's call them "items"), which in-turn include a `List<T>` of objects (let's call them "options"). I want to display a marker image on each item in the `listbox`, which basically indicates "all options of item are set".

The layout of the items are defined in a `dataTemplate` in `xaml`. there is basically a line:

```
<Image Source="{Binding options, Converter={StaticResource conv}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

which binds the image source to the before mentioned options list in the object

converter is defined as follows:

```
using Project.Model.Option;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Project.ViewModel.Converter
{
    class cStatusImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                BitmapImage failImage = new BitmapImage();
                failImage.BeginInit();
                failImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/view/Icons/failImage.png");
                failImage.EndInit();

                List<cOption> options = (List<cOption>)value;

                for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i ++)
                {
                    if (options[i].value == null)
                        return failImage;
                }

                BitmapImage successImage = new BitmapImage();
                successImage.BeginInit();
                successImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/view/Icons/successImage.png");
                successImage.EndInit();

                return successImage;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in the option definition

```
// value of option
    private string _value;
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_value!= value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("options");
            }
        }
    }
```

might be simple: the converter is only called upon adding an item to the list, but not when I change the value field of the options object though I'm firing OnPropertyChanged...

the "failImage" is displayed (so in principle code is working) it doesn't update however... So I'm doing something wrong when firing the `OnPropertyChanged` event(?)

Any help appreciated

BEGIN EDIT 08.10.2015 10.02:

Definition of "item":

```
using System;
using Project.Model.Option;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    class Item: ModelBase
    {
        #region properties
        // label of item
        public string label { get; set; }

        // item options
        public List<cOption> options {get; set;};
        #endregion
    }
}
```

END EDIT 08.10.2015 10.02

BEGIN EDIT 09.10.2015 14.24

Now this works if I put the `xml` tag somewhere in the window and point to the currently selected item

```
<Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Source="{Binding SelectedItem.AllOptionsSet, ElementName=lstSequence, Converter={StaticResource sic}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="15" Height="15"/>
```

but as soon I put that code into the `dataTemplate` (as aforementioned...) and bind like that

```
<Image Source="{Binding AllOptionsSet, Converter={StaticResource sic}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="15" Height="15"/>
```

it just doesn't step into the converter... The output window on the other hand doesn't show a binding error..

END EDIT 09.10.2015 14.24

BEGIN EDIT 09.10.2015 16.10

So I think I hunted this down to the following question: what could possibly be the reason for the fact, that a getter of a property is not executed albeit a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event for this property is triggered?

I'm really stuck on this. Anybody?

END EDIT 09.10.2015 16.10

BEGIN EDIT 09.10.2015 17.19

So I did get rid of the converter, by just setting a style trigger in the datatemplate:

```
<Image Width="15" Height="15" >
    <Image.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AllOptionsSet}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Icons/successImage.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AllOptionsSet}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Icons/failImage.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

So this also sets "failImage" correctly (since when adding an item to the list all "value" fields of all options are empty). It just doesn't update, when I'm calling `INPC(AllOptionsSet)`. So basically it seems that the GUI doesn't "listen" to the event(?)

END EDIT 09.10.2015 17.19

Comment: You're raising the `PropertyChanged` event for `options` rather than `value`, and I'm not sure I understand why (I have an idea), but this may be the root of your problem.  From what you've provided, it seems you realize that changes to individual items of a `List<T>` won't raise change notifications for the `List<T>` itself.  Thus, you'll need to listen to the change notifications of the list items yourself, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the list when this happens.

Comment: I'm rasing for "options" since I'm binding to "options". Raising for "value" would require binding to "value", which doesn't make sense if I need to check to whole List of options, does it?

Comment: Yea, but if `value` is a property on your `cOption` type (which appears to be the case unless I'm misreading your code), then `options` isn't even in scope, so raising the `PropertyChanged` event for it won't help.

Comment: "{Binding `options` Converter={StaticResource conv}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Where is your `options` property ?

Comment: options property is inside cOption

Comment: You're binding to `options`, which is a `List<cOption>` (as indicated by the code for the converter), but `options` is a property of the `cOption` class?  If the `cOption` type is infinitely nestable, I guess it's `cOption`s all the way down.

Comment: crap, that was ***: the List<cOption> (named "options") is hosted inside each "item"

Comment: @Joshua, Abin: The problem is not the binding itself - that works (cause when I add an item the converter is called and executed correctly, also the image appears). The problem is, if I change a value of an option, the change isn't notified to the GUI (although I'm firing "PropertyChanged" for "options" when I'm setting the value (I'm assuming that's the problem, because if I'm setting a breakpoint in the converter, it doesn't stop there)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you are binding to `options`, which is a `List<T>`, but your are firing INPC on a `cOption` item CONTAINED by the list.

You are not firing `INPC`, (or `INotifyCollectionChanged`) on the `list` itself, so the binding never updates.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly: you propose to throw INPC in the property "options" in the item? so basically something like`private List<cOption> _options;   public List<cOption> options
         {
            get
            {
                return _options;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _options)
                {
                    _options = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("options");
}
            }
        }` that doesn't change anything...

Comment: I'm not proposing anything, just pointing out why your binding is not updating. Personally I would do all this in the ViewModel and have an "AllOptionsChecked" property to bind your image to.

Comment: added an "AllOptionsChecked" property to item (not viewModel, but that shouldn't change anything (?)), which checks in the getter, whether all cOptions in the List<cOption> do have a value setting, bound imageSource to AllOptionsChecked and calling in the setter of "value" INPC("AllOptionsChecked"): strangly this acts excactly as the way I'm proposing, the break-point in the value converter is only hit when I'm adding an item to the list... what's going wrong here?